# JAXB classes for same parent and child tag name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have run into weird problem. I have one xml response coming from the server and the demo xml looks like:
http://www.javaexperience.com/catalog.xml

The root and one of the child tag have same name "Catalog" but different xml hierarchy.
When I run JAXB processor on the xsd generated from this xml, I get the error because Catalog.java was already generated from root tag and now can't be generated for child tag.

How should I resolve this problem.

P.S. I used http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html for getting xsd from demo xml.

Comment: Are you sure XSD is correct?

Comment: The XSD is valid. It is: http://www.javaexperience.com/CatalogByLocation.xsd